# How to replace an element in an array field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

Field tags is array in scenes document. I wanna replace element 'Bad' with 'Good' in the array as:

```
db.scenes.update({ 'tags': 'Bad' }, { $set: { 'tags.$' : 'Good' } }, { 'multi':true});
```

I don't know how to do it in doctrine. I tried

```
    $dm->createQueryBuilder('SceneBundle:Scene')
        ->update()
        ->field('tags.$')->set($tag)
        ->field('tags')->equals($oldTag)
        ->multiple(true)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

but not work.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about doctrine, but here's [how to replace an array element in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545448/mongodb-replace-specific-array-values).

Answer (score 2):

it's been a long time, but just to not leave this post without a good answer I found a link ([Mongodb array $push and $pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217874/mongodb-array-push-and-pull)) which can help us.

> The issue is that MongoDB doesn’t allow multiple operations on the
>   same property in the same update call. This means that the two
>   operations must happen in two individually atomic operations.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single replace function for this, but you can do it in one query by pulling all the 'Bad' out, and pushing 'Good' in

```
db.scenes.update({ 'tags': 'Bad' }, { $pull: { 'tags' : 'Bad' }, $push: { 'tags' : 'Good' } }, { 'multi':true});
```

The doctrine equivalent should be :

```
 $dm->createQueryBuilder('SceneBundle:Scene')
    ->update()
    ->field('tags')->pull('Bad')
    ->field('tags')->push('Good')
    ->field('tags')->equals('Bad')
    ->multiple(true)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Refer to the doctrine docs  here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

Comment: No, this does not work. I wrote this at first and mongod complained:`code`(Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers)

Comment: huh, probably three. Need find documents to be modified first

Comment: It doesn't need to be done twice in mongo. However, I'm not fluent with Doctrine to give you an answer. Try some options and post the answer here.

Comment: This don't woks for me... `errmsg: 'exception: Cannot update \'tags\' and \'tags\' at the same time`