# MongoDB Replace specific array values

Tags: arrays, mongodb

In MongoDB, I have a movie collection that has an array of languages , e.g.
`languages: [0:USA, 1: German, 2: French, ...etc]`

The array values are not in any particular order.

How can I now update an array value based on some specific value? Let's say I want to update all "French" and replace it with "Francais" for the entire collection. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `db.movies.updateMany({ "languages": "French" }, { "$set": { "languages.$": "Francais" } })`? Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

Comment: thank you, this did work indeed. I didnt know about that .$ syntax..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) which identifies the element in the `languages` array to update without explicitly specifying its position in the array i.e. instead of knowing the position in advance and updating the element as:

```
db.movies.updateMany(
    { "languages": "French" }, 
    { "$set": { "languages.2": "Francais" } }
)
```

you can just use the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator as:

```
db.movies.updateMany(
    { "languages": "French" }, 
    { "$set": { "languages.$": "Francais" } }
)
```

---

Alternatively using the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) for update operations:

```
db.movies.updateMany(
    { "languages": "French" }, 
    [
        { "$set": { 
            "languages": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$languages",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": ["$$this", "French"] }, 
                            "Francais", 
                            "$$this"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        } }
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 14):

In case you have duplicate entries in your array like this:

```
"languages" : [ 
    "USA", 
    "German", 
    "French",
    "French"
]
```

You can use the following syntax to **replace all occurrences** starting with MongoDB v3.5.12 ([documentation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243))

```
db.movies.updateMany(
    { "languages": "French" },
    { "$set": { "languages.$[filter]": "Francais" } },
    { "arrayFilters": [ { "filter": "French" } ] }
)
```

Strictly speaking, the `{ "languages": "French" }` filter is not needed. It will, however, speed up things by leveraging an index on "languages" in case there is one. If that's not needed/wanted, passing a simple `{}` value as the first parameter works as well.