# Mongoose, find and update items in an array which matches a criteria (only mathcing item in the array should be changed)

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a fresh junior web developer. I have an array of strings in Mongodb. I just want to find the items in the array, deleting it and updating with new one.
I know it is a basic operation, since I dont know the index of the element in the array, I dont know how to change it.
Image array in the database, only includes the image file names. Instead of image file names, I want to update them with base64 strings.
First, with Nodejs fs module, I get the file names (they are the same image names in mongodb images array).  Now, by mapping these image names, I'd like to find them in db images array and update them with base64 string.
How to use findandupdate ?
Merci d'avance.

My Model:

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(

  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    
    image: [{ type: String, required: true }],
}
  
);
```

My Code:

```
productRouter.get("/updateAllImagePaths", async (req, res) => {
  const img_folder = "/client/public/images";  //There are hundreds of images
  const arr = fs.readdirSync(img_folder); // I get the image file names

  for (let i of arr) {
  let img_name = i;   // database includes only image file names like "computer.jpg"
  let img_base64 = fs.readFileSync(`${img_folder}/book2.jpg`, "base64"); // I change images with base64 strings

  const item = await Product.findOneAndUpdate({

    // I want to find img_name matching in the images array, and change it with img_base64 string

  });

  console.log(item);
  

}})
```

Comment: I think this has already been solved. Check it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54815993/8496328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution below it worked. However, it is too slow for loading.
Any suggestion to store images in MERN stack e-commerce web-site?                     I tried cloudinary in frontend, it seems fast enough. What's the best way to store and show images in React-node-mongodb stack?
Thanks.

```
productRouter.get("/seed", async (req, res) => {
  const img_folder = "C:/Users/../Desktop/Projects/../client/public/images";
  const arr = fs.readdirSync(img_folder);
  const result = [];

  for (let i of arr) {
    let img_base64 = fs.readFileSync(`${img_folder}/${i}`, "base64");
    let img = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img_base64;

    const item = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(
      { image: `/images/${i}` },
      { $set: { "image.$[]": img } }
    );
    result.push(i);
    console.log(i);
  }
  res.send(result);
}
```